# Where is wmi hpqBIntM provider dll located?

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-service

I have an HP PC with windows 10 x64 where is installed WMI provider hpqBIntM in root\\wmi. In C:\Windows\system32 there is no such .mof file with hpqBIntM class description.

Question: where can I find files (.dll and .mof) associated with this WMI class hpqBIntM on my PC? Or where can I get some more information about this class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a BIOS provider, exposed by the BIOS through ACPI. So you will not find an actual provider on disk. You can view the MOF using WMIExplorer, but it probably won't help you much since you won't know how to encode the payloads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WMIExplorer](https://wmie.codeplex.com/) to get information about WMI classes. After getting CLSID of class instance you can search HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for this CLSID to find .dll where this class is registered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I did not find CLSID in WMIExplorer. Here is the [proof](https://s23.postimg.org/mptvxv8fv/wmiexplorer_class.png). But right click on a class hpqBIntM allowed to see a *.mof [file](https://s30.postimg.org/e7tzzbpwh/wmiexplorer_mof.png). GUID in a mof file was not found in regedit anywhere in x64 or x32 modes. Also I tried to find this *.mof file on a hard drive but unsuccessfully. Can you give me more advice or help?

Comment: Check also Program Files folder, this looks like some Hewlett Packard software, so maybe in c:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard

Comment: Well, as I know now, InstanceName = ACPI means that this WMI code located in ACPI. If I got it right. So, it cannot be found easily on Windows/Linux. Only with some soft you can extract ACPI code and find it there.